# Can nightwatch css selectors locate items within an unordered list created by a bootstrapped angularjs?

Tags: nightwatch.js

When run in nightwatch.js the following code:

```
    module.exports = {
      'simple test todomvc with angular2' : function (client) {
        client
          .url('http://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/')
          .waitForElementVisible('input.new-todo', 1000)        // this works
          .assert.visible('input.new-todo')                     // this passes
          .setValue('input.new-todo', 'task A\r\n')
          .setValue('input.new-todo', 'task B\r\n')
          .pause(1000)
          .assert.visible('ul.todo-list')                       // this passes
          .assert.visible('ul.todo-list li:first-child')        // this fails
          .end();
      }
    };
```

results in the following output:

```
    Running:  simple test todomvc with angular2
       ? Element  was visible after 724 milliseconds.
       ? Testing if element  is visible.
       ? Testing if element  is visible.
       ? Testing if element  is visible. Element could not be located.  - expected "true" but got: null
      ...  ERROR: Unable to locate element: "ul.todo-list li:first-child" using: css selector
```

**Why is it that the todo-list is visible, but the first child element of that list is not visible?**

**What is the best way to locate and inspect the elements within the todo-list?**

(Note that the app under test is implemented with AngularJS, but without using the ng-app directive. The todo-list is generated with Angular's ng-for directive, which is imported via some kind of bootstrapped Angular - if I understand correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code for a working test:

```
    module.exports = {
      'simple test todomvc with angular2' : function (client) {
        client
          .url('http://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/')
          .waitForElementVisible('input.new-todo', 1000)
          .assert.visible('input.new-todo')
          .setValue('input.new-todo', 'task A\r\n')
          .setValue('input.new-todo', 'task B\r\n')
          //.pause(2000)
          .assert.visible('ul.todo-list')
          //.assert.visible('ul.todo-list > li:nth-child(2) > div > label')
          .assert.containsText('ul.todo-list > li:nth-child(2) > div > label', 'task A')
          .assert.containsText('ul.todo-list > li:nth-child(3) > div > label', 'task B')
          .end();
      }
    };
```

As you can see, I needed to learn a little more about how to specify the proper CSS selector.